# Updateing Android SDK in Eclipse ADT to API 19 from API 18

Tags: eclipse, adt

Is there anyway to update Android SDK version to API 19.0 or higher from API 17.0 without using SDK Manager in eclipse? I mean to say can I download the update files separately in some computer and include the downloaded files in the android-eclipse directory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look [here for instructions](http://qdevarena.blogspot.com/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html)
Quoting from there:

> Open in browser
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml
>
> For e.g. if you want to download Android SDK for version 4.0.3 for all
>   platforms, you could look up that XML file. You will find a block
>   under tag SDK 4.0.3 like this

```
<sdk:archive arch="any" os="any">

<sdk:size>44758833</sdk:size>
<sdk:checksum type="sha1">f2aa75133c29916b0b0b984974c2d5e46cb09e9c</sdk:checksum>
<sdk:url>android-15_r01.zip</sdk:url>
</sdk:archive>
```

> So the URL will be is
>   http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-15_r01.zip

In such a way resolve the needed links. I've checked that there are file names for all versions upto the latest